# Using the ":" operator

Tags: java, operators

I know this is a basic question, but all the documentation I read doesn't seem to answer my question: What does the ":" operator do?

I get the impression that if I do something like `for(item : list)`, the for loop would go through every item of a list. Is this right?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: I don't think there is a separate `:` operator. I consider it part of the `for` statement syntax.

Comment: Just to be complete the : is also used in trinaries.

a = (b > 0) ? 4 : 3;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, what you have there is a for each statement. The one you have is not quite correct, if you have a `List<String>` called list for example then you could do something like this:

```
for (String item: list) {
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

As an aside there is also another use for ":" as part of a ternary expression, e.g.

```
int i = y < 0 ? 10 : 100;
```

which is the same as:

```
int i;

if (y < 0) {
   i = 10;
} else {
   i = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's right. It's not really an operator as such - it's part of the syntax for the [*enhanced for loop*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) which was introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have an iterable object, you can do something like:

```
for (Object o : iterableObj) {
    o.doSomething();
}
```

which is equivalent (in functionality) to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterableObj.length(); i++) {
    Object o = iterableObj.get(i);
    o.doSomething();
}
```